# RoutingError No route matches [GET] "/missing.png"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, video

Routing error occur with rails 3, paperclip and s2 bucket. I am tring to attach video in my application.But it fails and throws the following

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/missing.png"):
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
```

I included videos.js file in my javascript. And i am not able to see missing.png in any of my folder. so, why i am getting this error? From where i can get missing.png file?

Comment: can you post your code please

Answer (score 0):

I think you copied some example of paperclip to your app. Check model, which has attachments. You should see something like that:

```
has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :medium => "250x250>", :thumb => "150x150>" },
:default_url => "/system/missing/:style/missing.jpg",
:convert_options => {:all => '-quality 80' }
```

**default_url** in that case is path to image which should be shown if object has no attached picture. In your case you should delete this line if you dont want some photo to be shown if object dont have attached video clip.

But if you really want some image to be shown if your object dont have attached video, then you should place file `missing.png` to `/public` folder of your app.

Comment: I can give path to s3 storage in has_Attached_file. And i am not mention missing.png in my application. where it comes?

Comment: You can do a full-project search of "missing.png". I think that somewhere in project there is reference to it.